# Magento and refurbished products

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm working on a Magento store, containing 3,000 products, with a main stock and a main price updated automatically from SAGE (each 5 minutes).
Here is the specificity : products can be both IN THE MAIN STOCK and IN THE REFURB STOCK, with different prices. SAGE tell me, each 5 minutes, if the product is in the refurb stock, and what is the refurb price. That can concern 20 products, or 100 products in the same time.
For each product I have from SAGE:
- stock
- price
- stock_refurb
- price_refurb

I know about configurable product, but I think this is a pity to manage 9,000 products in the back-office (3,000 configurable, 3,000 simple in main stock, 3,000 simple in refurb stock), for maybe only 20 products in the refurb stock at the same time...

I have also thought about creating a simple temporary copy of the simple product (in main stock) when I have the product in the refurb stock, but I need to keep the historic of the orders for the customers. And if the Main stock product changes (description, images or else), I need to maintain the Refurb stock product consistant.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Curious what your problem is?

Comment: Hi Rob. 1) I will have to manage 9000 products instead of 3000, only for 20/30 products concerned 2) Magento duplicate ALL product information from the configurable product to the simple products 3) Magento don't apply the modifs in the configurable product in the associated simple products 4) I can't display in a search result the product in the Main Stock AND the product in the Refurb Stock... And there are more problems :)